# In Dragon's Egg, the effect on time due to extremely high gravity is inconsistent

Tags: interstellar, gravity, time-dilation, black-hole, dragons-egg

This has been messing with my head for a while.

The Cheela in/on Dragon's Egg book/planet, had their time move *much* faster, compared to the humans out in the space. This was explained as due to the extremely high gravity of their neutron star planet.  **What is the fictional physics occurring on Cheela to cause the time speed up?**

But in reality AND any fictional universe that acts like reality, high gravity acts to *slow* time down. This effect was notably portrayed in Interstellar -- when the expedition party land on the watery planet that's extremely close to a black hole, their time is slowed down, compared to the human out in space.

I'm missing something simple here. Can someone help solve this for me please.

Comment: The answer given explains it. As you said, GR will **slow down** time -- with a factor of [1.7 to 1.4](https://9to5science.com/gravitational-time-dilation-and-neutron-stars). But the fact that the cheela are made of nuclei and not of atoms means that their "chemistry" runs about a million times **faster**. So the chemistry speedup far outweighs the GR slowdown.

Comment: @RossPresser Note that Dragon's Egg is _not_ fully a neutron star (hence the quasi-atomic matter present on the surface) and is far more than 1.5 times the Schwarzchild radius; it's actually almost 7 times the Schwarzchild radius, so tau on the surface is only about 1.08.

Comment: Unfortunately, all your edit did was change this opinion-based (comparing two different series) to asking for real world science (comparing the fictional universe to our own). If you haven't yet, I'd suggest taking the [tour] and visiting the [help].

Comment: @Skooba Dragon's Egg made a big play of being hard science, being written by a professional physicist. Surely it is reasonable to ask what the in-universe explanation for an apparently paradoxical phenomenon is, given the hard science credentials. In particular the question is not asking for real-world physics answers, just the explanation given in the book.

Comment: Lots of comments deleted following the edit to the question, making it about comparing *Dragon's Egg* to actual physics rather than comparing *Dragon's Egg* to *Interstellar*. I tried to leave the most still-relevant comments, but let me know if anything important has gone.

Comment: Hey, sorry, is that also part of the policy here? Almost feels like rewriting history, Orwellian style.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're mistaking the "living rate" of the Cheela against the Einsteinian General Relativity time dilation in *Interstellar*.

This was explained early in *Dragon's Egg*, during the exposition about how life evolved in the degenerate matter crust of a neutron star.  The explanation was that, because degenerate matter is much more compact than normal matter (due to the electrons being *not quite* smashed into the nucleus, which would cause them to fuse with protons to produce neutronium), all the pseudo-chemical reactions between them proceed at thousands or tens of thousands of times the rate of reactions between normal matter atoms.

The time dilation effect of a neutron star would make perception of time there slow down (one year at the station in synchronous orbit with its orbiting monopolium tidal counterbalances would be something more than a year Earth time), just as it did deep down in the gravity well of Gargantua  -- but living tens of thousands of times faster and in almost the same level of time dilation let the Cheela live and advance through hundreds of generations in the space of a few days of human time.

Comment: I would disagree with "much more" -- the tau factor ranges from 1.7 to 1.4 depending on the ratio of the actual radius to the Schwarzchild radius.

Comment: Thanks @Zeiss for the detailed explanation. I think I'll go reread that part from Dragon's Egg once again. I think I see where I got the wrong impression. Although the first paragraph answers my question, thank you very much for going into details. I needed that.

Comment: @RossPresser Edited -- you're right, tau 1.4-1.7 wouldn't give a HUGE differential.  There would certainly be some differential between the surface and the human station, too, but the Cheela's "rate of living" grossly overrides that.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I replied to Ross's similar comment on the main question, but it was removed.  Maybe it will stick here.  The tau factor of 1.4+ is based on a neutron star with a radius of approximately 1.5 times its Schwarzchild radius.  We know the mass and radius of Dragon's Egg, and it's about 7 times its Schwarzchild radius, so tau will be much lower.  I used a couple of online calculators and got approximately 1.08.

Comment: @DavidW still very noticeable in terms of having to retune Earthbound receivers to get their reports (not to mention a small additional redshift for the light/radio having to climb out of the rest of the gravity well).  Amounts to more than two days over the course of a year.

Comment: Oh, you misunderstand.  That is the tau experienced by the Cheela.  The *Dragon Slayer*, orbiting at 406km out, experiences a tau of less than 1.002.

Comment: @DavidW So only a day every year and a half.  *Still* going to be noticeable with electronic communication.  And still not enough difference to matter compared to the "rate of living" of the Cheela.

Comment: Exactly.  Detectible (electronically) but imperceptible to normal human communication (between *St. George* and *Dragon Slayer*). Vastly less important than the 2/3s light-speed lag.  Completely inconsequential relative to the massive experiential time delta between humans and Cheela.  I had all this written up as an answer (like yours, but with numbers), but was too slow.

Comment: The gravitational time dilation formula is pretty simple: `sqrt(1 - rs/r)`, where `rs` is the Schwarzschild radius. But there's also some velocity time dilation. Do we know how fast Dragon's Egg is spinning? FWIW, the tidal forces near a neutron star are rather intense, even in freefall. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/631427/123208

Comment: @PM2Ring The Author did postulate a 6-mass ring of monopolium spheres surrounding *Dragon Slayer* as a tidal countermeasure; else the environment would have been unsurvivable for humans.

Comment: @PM2Ring Dragon's Egg is spinning 5.018 times per second, and *Dragon Slayer* is in synchronous orbit at 416km, giving it a speed of approximately 4.38% c.  This is not a lot, but does add a fraction of time dilation to the gravitational tau.  I'm not sure I combined them properly, but the total tau is still less than 1.003.

Comment: Ah , ok. The SR time dilation on the surface is negligible, around 1.0000044. The pseudo-chemical basis of the cheela biology is primarily based on the strong force, electromagnetic (and weak) interactions are (probably) irrelevant, as well as being glacially slow from the cheela's POV.

Answer (score 5):

The "Technical Appendix" at the back of *Dragon's Egg* is very detailed in the description of the neutron star, the cheela, the *Dragon Slayer*'s orbit, and everything else about the expedition.

The neutron star itself has half a solar mass (approximately 1e30 kg), a diameter of 10km and rotates every 0.1993s.  A gravitational time dilation calculator says that tau on the surface would be approximately 1.083, and the rotational velocity (315 km/s) contributes no significant additional time dilation

The *Dragon Slayer* in turn is orbiting *Dragon's Egg* in a synchronous orbit at an altitude of 406km. It orbits every 0.1993s (the rotational speed of *Dragon's Egg*) or 5.018 orbits/s.  The radius of Dragon's Egg is 10km, so the *Slayer* travels 416 * 2 * π * 5.018 = 13 116 km/s (4.375% c), which only gives a velocity time dilation of 1.00096.  (Less than 1 in 1000.)  The *Egg* has 0.5 solar masses, which at a distance of 416km gives a gravity time dilation of 1.00178, slightly less than twice the velocity time dilation.

I'm not sure these results can be added together, but in any event the total time dilation experienced by the crew on the *Slayer* will be less than half a percent.  Over the course of the 8-day mission (which is cut short in any event) they would experience no more than an hour's difference from the crew on the *St. George*.

The cheela are a completely different story.  Per the appendix, the Cheela live and *experience* time approximately a million times faster than we do.

> The atomic nuclei that make up the cheela do not have captive electron clouds to keep them isolated from each other, but instead share a "sea" of free electrons.  Because of the resulting close proximity of the nuclei, it is as easy for cheela nuclei to exchange neutrons as it is for human atoms to exchange electrons.  The nuclei couple into "nuclear bonded molecules" by neutron exchange.  Since the cheela use **nuclear coupling instead of molecular coupling** in their bodies, their **rate of living is about one million times that of humans**.
>
> <sub><sup>*Dragon's Egg*, "Technical Appendix"</sup></sub>

Note that this has nothing to do with relativistic time dilation. It is purely because instead of (slow) chemical reactions, their bodies/metabolisms operate on strong nuclear reactions.  So even if tau (on the surface of their star) is 1.083, it makes effectively no difference in how fast they experience time.

Comment: Note that I'm explicitly ignoring *Interstellar* here because it's not necessary to answer the question and it's only causing a misunderstanding of gravitational time dilation.